# How to upload .csv file?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code and I got an error saying:

> D:\VPN_TFS_ETP\ETP_DEV\EndoAdmin\Uploads\Employers_C_d5pjixjyhcwojaypfyw0paoj_Master
>   Client Report-Reloadable.csv' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the
>   path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the
>   server on which the file resides.

The file extension that I want to upload is .csv.

```
Dim oOLEDBConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim oDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim oFile As HttpPostedFile, strFileName As String, strOrigName As String

Try

    strOrigName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.Value)
    oFile = File1.PostedFile
    '
    ' Keep Copy in the Server
    '
    strFileName = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & "Uploads\Employers_" & oUser.Usr_UserID & "C_" & Session.SessionID & "_" & strOrigName
    oFile.SaveAs(strFileName)

    'strFileName = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & "Uploads\Co_" & Session.SessionID & "_" & strOrigName
    'oFile.SaveAs(strFileName)

    Dim OConnectionString As String, myStrmReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(strFileName)
    'OConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + strFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

    Try
        'OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""
        OConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + strFileName + ";Extended Properties='Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'"
        'OConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + strFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'"
        'OConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= " + strFileName + "; Extended Properties=HTML Import;"
        oOLEDBConn.ConnectionString = OConnectionString
        oOLEDBConn.Open()

    Catch ex1 As Exception
        If ex1.Message.StartsWith("External table is not in the expected format") Then
            'Try
            '    oOLEDBConn.Close()

            '    ' Load as HTML
            '    OConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + strFileName + ";Extended Properties='HTML Import;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'"
            '    oOLEDBConn.ConnectionString = OConnectionString
            '    oOLEDBConn.Open()
            'Catch ex2 As Exception
            '    lblFeedBack.Text = "22:" & ex2.Message
            '    Exit Sub
            'End Try
            lblFeedBack.Text = ex1.Message '& " Please see below."
            Exit Sub
        Else
            lblFeedBack.Text = ex1.Message
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

When using connection strings to access csv files, you don't point the filename you want to open, but the folder where you file is. Later on querys you specify the filename.
So, you code could be like this:

```
Dim folderWhereIsYourCsv = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & "Uploads\"
OConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + folderWhereIsYourCsv + ";Extended Properties='Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'"
oOLEDBConn.ConnectionString = OConnectionString
oOLEDBConn.Open()
```

Later, when you want to run by the file content. you should do something like:

```
Dim fileNameOfYourCsv = "Employers_" & oUser.Usr_UserID & "C_" & Session.SessionID & "_" & strOrigName
Dim cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & fileNameOfYourCsv, oOLEDBConn);
```